# How do I append a style to existing inline style in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a usecase where I'm making an email and adding a variable class to it, which well get it's value from backend while processing. Problem is for that variable class, there can be two values and for both values I need to add some style to the element bearing that class.

```
let sheet = document.createElement('style');
                                    sheet.innerHTML = ".displayfield{display : block;} " +
                                        ".ndisplayfield{display : none;}";
                                    activeEles[0].classList.add('${displayClass}');
                                    activeEles[0].appendChild(sheet);
```

where `activeEles[0]` is the element and `${displayClass}` is the variable class. and sheet is the style I want to append.

how can I do so?

Comment: May I ask why you use '${displayClass}' as a class name? If you wish to add variable as a class you should make var myClass = "displayClass" and just add(myClass)

Comment: I want to add the class later on using es6 templating

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
var css = '.displayfield{display : block;}.ndisplayfield{display : none;}',
    sheet = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

activeEles[0].appendChild(sheet);
activeEles[0].classList.add("displayClass")
```

Comment: it's not workin, when I send the email, the style tag is lost

Comment: The problem is not with your javascript.

Comment: yes I searched the net and got to know it later, that it is problem with Gmail, because on Yahoo mail I'm getting the same. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: thanks for your guidance, I used jsdom library of npm and enabled it in inline styling based on the condition on which I was deciding value of displayClass